# Allow login authentication on our web-site using Microsoft Azure MFA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web, multi-factor-authentication

We have a company web-site developed in ASP.NET MVC that currently allows our customers to login using login name and password. These customers are in our SQL Server database. The customers once logged in can use our services.

We would like to authenticate our customers using Azure Multi-Factor Authentication feature.
How can we implement Microsoft Azure Multi-Factor authentication in our use-case ?
Is it required that our website should be deployed on Azure App service.

Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to this [Add sign-in to Microsoft to an ASP.NET MVC web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp).

Or

[Configure your App Service or Azure Functions app to use Azure AD login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) for a simplified setup.

You don't need Azure Web Apps to enable MFA, you can [enforce MFA using Conditional Access Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa) or similar [Azure AD features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults).

You can then add an Id column into your SQL database user table to store the Azure AD User Object Id (which you can obtain from his Azure AD token [sub claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#claims)) as a reference for future operations.

Comment: Alferdo, I would like to register user with login credentials stored in our SQL Server DB and create an Azure AD User object for that user. Upon login, once I authenticate the user with credentials in our DB, I would like to invoke Azure AD authentication using MFA behind the scenes. Can you help me identify the authentication flow I would need to have on my web-site.

Comment: I mean after custom authentication can I do Azure AD authentcation of that mapped user within the server side code to invoke MFA or Do I need to get the user sign-in to Azure AD form my web-site to invoke MFA.

Comment: @Gags you can register your users using [MS Graph Create User endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) or the [New-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) cmdlet.

Comment: @Gags yes you need to do an interactive Azure AD login using [authorization code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) or [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) to get MFA.

Comment: Can we do the interactive Azure AD sign-in via popup window on my web site instead of getting redirected to AD sign-in web site. Thank you.